# database design issue...for booking app

Tags: mysql, database

I have 4 tables,one is credentials(it holds an id, email and password), the other 2 are for business users  and regular users of the app.
The business users table holds crID(foreign key)name,lastname,address etc...
The regular users table holds crID(foreign key),name,lastname etc...

The 4th is the booking table, it holds a bookingID, bookedfrom,bookedfor(the last 2 being foreign keys that point to the credentials table).

If a regular user registers in the site he closes a bookingslot and that is stored in the booking table, his name,last name are stored in the regular users table and his credentials in the credentials table.

The business user table just holds the business user for which a booking is made by the regular users.

Here is a graph:
[db image](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=BE27434B2AAC8130!262&authkey=!AIZLc8qIX7DAzwg&v=3)

The question is what to do if a regular user does not choose the web to make the booking but makes a call. The business users are given the option to make the booking "manually" also. I am just having difficulty how to integrate that in the db.

As I see it I need to make the following:

1. Create a booking slot in the bookings table
2. Create a new regular user entry in the regular users table and at the same time create another column that would indicate if the user is registered or not.
3. create an entry in the credentials table but without password/email since this he will not be a registered user...he just made a booking using the phone.

WHat is your opinion.If you want I will post some show create statements. I think I made my point.

Comment: Do you really need separate tables for the two types of users?

Comment: You are not the first person which tells me that. I did in the first place because more data must be entered for the business users. Secondly I am reluctant to change this now because much code is written based on this design-but if I have to alter the design to make it more practical I will do it

Comment: I'd store that in an annexe table and (LEFT) OUTER JOIN that onto the main table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would personally merge `business users`, `normal users` and optionally `credentials` in one single `users`table.

Since I don't see the need of two seperate tables for your users, it would simplify drastically your data model. You just need a flag to determine if the user is a business user or a normal user.

For the rest, I think that having a null password is enough to determine if the user hasn't registered yet.

Comment: the only thing that worries me is changing all that php code which iis based on the existing database design

Comment: @DimitrisPapageorgiou Don't change the database if you think it is not worth it. I sometimes keep things I consider not very good because the benefits I would get are less important than the work (and the risk of regressions) it involves. On the other hand if there is still much work to do the change might be valuable.

Comment: I will stick with the current design...finish the project and then see if the change is indeed necessary.

Comment: Nonetheless...I may be forced to change the design cause as I see now there are some issues trying to implement what I want with the current design. I will make a different post to discuss these issues as a last effort to avoid a costly(in terms of time) db redesign

Comment: If you realize you need refactor your DB, I think it is better to do it as soon as possible but once again you need to evaluate the effort / gain ration.

Comment: I will make the post and see my options,I hope I will mot have to redesign.